# Is it possible to change the sortupicon and sortdown icon of antd table

Tags: reactjs, antd

we have currently problem pertaining customizing of sortupicon and sortdown icon of ant design table. my question, is it allowed to customize the icons on the table? or ant design has no function for that? I have a lot of research today, the thread has no right answer.

**Here is the illustration:**

[image: Illustration]

```
<Table
    
    dataSource={data}
    columns={columns}
    onChange={onChangeSort}
    size="small"
    rowSelection={{
        type: "checkbox",
        ...rowSelection,
        }}
    pagination={false}
    footer={() => `Total No. of Checks: ${data.length}`}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. I've found one solution

```css
.ant-table-column-sorter {
  display: none;
}
```

```
export default function App() {
  const [orderDirection, setOrderDirection] = React.useState();

  const changeOrder = (direction) => () => {
    setOrderDirection(direction);
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      title: (
        <div>
          Age <button onClick={changeOrder("ascend")}>up</button>
          <button onClick={changeOrder("descent")}>down</button>
        </div>
      ),
      dataIndex: "age",
      key: "age",
      sorter: (a, b) => a.age - b.age,
      sortOrder: orderDirection
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The full example you can see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-https-rvzjl?file=/src/App.js